# Save values from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I made similar code in other workbooks without trouble.

I get the error "400".

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Tool")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("SaveFile")

    v1 = Array("D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10", "D11", "D12", "D13", "H4", "H5", "H8", "H9", "H10", "H11", "H12", "H13", "E17")
    v2 = Array("C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V")
    rw = sh2.Cells(Rows_Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    For i = LBound(v1) To UBound(v1)
        Set r1 = sh1.Range(v1(i))
        Set r2 = sh2.Cells(rw, v2(i))
        r2.Value = r1.Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

With `Option Explicit` I get rw variable is not defined.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me after fixing two things: declaring `Dim i As Long` and setting `rw = sh2.Cells(sh2.Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`. Notice the `sh2.Cells.Rows.Count` value for the rows and it references the worksheet `sh2`.

Comment: Note: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module.

Comment: FYI - "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Do you get an error, or maybe your code does something unexpected?  Always helps to say what the actual problem is.

Comment: After doing that, I'm having a different problem- previously it wasn't running at all, now it's telling me that the rw variable is not defined

Comment: If I remove "Option Explicit", I get the error "400"

Answer (score 0):

I replaced some piece of code as follows:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
    Dim i, rw, Rows_Count As Integer 'you forgot some variables

    Rows_Count = 0 'This, obviously, is just an example. I have no idea what the value should be.
```